# Azure static web app custom domain, how to solve "The custom domain has not been resolving to your static web app and has expired"

Tags: azure

Our sites are hosting with Adobe AEM.  We use Azure traffic manager to manage DNS switching, so we can switch to a site down holding page which we host on Azure Static Apps.

The static web app has a validated custom domain which is our main sites domain.

This has worked really well for about a year. Now we just switched to the site down in traffic manager, and got SSL errors with the static hosting.  We see our custom domains have this error next to them:

```
The custom domain has not been resolving to your static web app and has expired.
```

Presumably the only solution is to delete the custom domains, re add and re validate them.

This is a real same, as using traffic manager and static web apps is the perfect site down solution except for this show stopper.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever found a solution?

Looks like there is a autorenewal in place...

To get it working I found a issue on github: https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/888

haven't tested it yet (not even sure if this helps in my specific case) but looks promising...